# html5 select tag set to transparent and different color when option is highlighted

Tags: html, select

we have the following code which is a html5 select dropdown menu:

```
    <!doctype html>
    <select name="indexCombobox1">
    <option selected value="null">    Sort By:</option>
    <option value="most_recent">    Most Recent</option>
    <option value="most_popular">    Most Popular</option>
    <option value="featured">    Featured</option>
    </select>
```

is there a data attribute that can set the drop down background transparent so that you can see what's behind the drop down menu? is there a data attribute that changes the option highlight from default blue to a different color, e.g. yellow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am increasingly using the [jqtransform library](http://www.dfc-e.com/metiers/multimedia/opensource/jqtransform/) to style form elements for both mobile webapps and HTML websites.

I can't confirm if it will enable you to make the background transparent, but it can do just about everything else to form elements.

Answer (score 1):

CSS(3) should do the trick. Something like:

```
option:hover {
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}
```

Edit:
With jquery instead of css:

```
$('option').hover(function() {
     $(this).css(backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, .2)');
}, function(){
    $(this).css(backgroundColor: 'blue'); //or something else you consider 'normal'
});
```

Comment: can the option:hover be done inline, e.g. <option value="most_recent" style="option:hover{background-color:rgba(0,0,0,.2);}">Most Recent</option>

Comment: No, you need the selector. But you could use, although I don't recommend it, the onmouseover event and call a js function in there that adjusts the css.

Comment: if i need the selector, then i am going to have to use jquery. if that's the case, then what is its syntax to call the selector? i assume i can then call the jquery function by using a class attribute in the select tag. fwiw, i was hoping html5 would dumb it down so that ajax/css wouldn't be needed to handle a transparent background. instead it would as easy as simply setting a data attribute, e.g. <!doctype html><select data-attr="transparent">.